# Getting a specific row other than first()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I'm having a little problem with laravel that may be easily solved. To be short, the situation is: I have two tables, one for the users and the other one for products that has a column 'user_id' so I can identify the associated user.

In Laravel, I can use

```
$user = Sentry::getUser();        //Or Auth::user() if you're not using Sentry
$products = DB::table('table2')->where('user_id',$user->id);
```

And that should give me every product that user has. Good.

Now I want to show the products individually on screen, but unfortunately that doesn't work. It seems I can't echo this information in a string because it's made of multiple rows. I get

`Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string`

For the solution, since the maximum associated products I allowed in the system is 3, I came up with the idea of getting each row separately and echoing them. For the first one, it's simple: `$products->first();` but I have no idea on how to get the other two.

And maybe I'm being a newbie here, but I don't think I can use the products' id info since $products->id returns an error.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what  you see the output when you print the products `print_r($products);`

Comment: u can use the `->get()` just like normal and in the view chose the row u want by `$bla[0,1,2,etc..]->column_name` or use `->skip(how_many)->get()` but again this doesn't limit to a single row ,u will still need to process it even further in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `take`, limit the number of results to three and then print out every one with a foreach loop. Docs: [Laravel Queries, see `skip` and `take`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects).

`$products = DB::table('table2')->where('user_id',$user->id)->take(3)->get()`

Then, inside your view, you can just iterate through this data:

`@foreach($products as $p)`

Alternatively, in your PHP you can iterate through this data using something like:

`foreach ($products as $product) { var_dump($product); }`

(You are getting that error because you are trying to output a result object as a whole, and not the data it contains. Using the loop actually fetches the data from the result object so you can then use the loop variable (`$product`) normally.)

Comment: That's it. As I noticed after reading Surya's and Marcin's answers, I was not echoing the data, but the object as a whole. And using `@foreach` solved it. By the way, the Laravel documentation doesn't explain what the argument inside `->take()` stands for. Is it like "take the three first objects?". Thanks for the help! I'm marking this as the solution since it explains in more detail than the other answers.

Comment: Yep. `take(n)` says *I'm only interested in the first `n` items*. Just like `skip(n)` says *I'm interested in everything except the first `n` items*.

Answer (score 1):

To get data from database you can use one one those methods: `all`, `get`, or `first`.

Using `all`:

```
$products = DB::table('table2')->all();
```

you are getting all the products.

Using `first` you can use conditions but you will get only first record that fulfil conditions:

```
$products = DB::table('table2')->where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
```

Using `get` you can use conditions and you will get all the records that fulfil those conditions:

```
$products = DB::table('table2')->where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
```

So in your case you want to use `get` to get data from database.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using

```
$products = DB::table('table2')->where('user_id',$user->id);
```

Then **$products** is an array and you do not have to **echo** an **array**.
To display the products you need to use a foreach loop like below

```
foreach ( $products as $key => $product ) {
   var_dump( $product );
}
```

If you want to show only three products, then you can use **for** loop inside **foreach**.

You can learn more about **foreach** from below link

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @ Down-voter: in Question @gabriel-rebello has written "I came up with the idea of getting each row separately and echoing them. For the first one, it's simple: $products->first(); but I have no idea on how to get the other two.". That's why I have written how to echo information separately using foreach loop. It will be good learning for me if you leave comment for the reason to down-vote.

Comment: Good! I didn't even think of **foreach**. Guess I still have a lot to learn. Querying with `->get();` to actually get an array of objects from the db and using `@foreach` on my view solved my problem. Thanks a lot Surya and Marcin!